# Getting "unknown variable x" or "ValueError" when putting a variable with the "type" of "int" in a method's parameter i.e.".remove()"

Tags: python, valueerror, traceback

Why is the name(variable) being considered "unknown variable 'x' " by the interpreter and not be taken as the "value" it has.`

```
list_of_names = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
name = 0
for name in range(100):
    counter = list_of_names.count(name)
    while counter > 1:
            list_of_names.remove(name)

print(list_of_names)
```

`
**Output shown:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x", line 6, in <module>
    list_of_names.remove(name)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You never re-calculate the value of `counter`.  The second time through the loop, `name` is 1 and `counter` is 5.  The `while counter > 1` loop runs forever, but it crashes on the sixth iteration, because all of the ones have already been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while counter > 1:
        list_of_names.remove(name)
```

That loop will (try) to run forever, because you're not changing `counter` inside the loop.

If it started at, say, 5, then it will be 5 forever because nothing in the loop changes it.  Eventually you will remove the last occurrence of `name` from the list, and then the next loop iteration will crash.

Comment: thanks bruh! Your explanation was simple and initutive. So, if there is no value on the last iteration, why does the interpreter take it an "unknown" instead of "None"

Comment: I don't understand.  The error message is `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.  I don't see the word "unknown" anywhere...

Comment: yeah, you're right. So  the interpreter is using  "x" as the name for a "value" it thinks does not exists or is not found.

Answer (score 1):

OP if you're trying to remove duplicates, use:

```
list(set(list_of_names))
```

`set(iterable)` ignores duplicates.

---

Here's [the documentation for `list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> s.remove(x)
> remove the first item from s where s[i] is equal to x
> (3)

Note footnote (3)

> 3. remove raises ValueError when x is not found in s.

---

Here's an example of what's happening:

```
s = [1, 2, 3]
s.remove(1)
print(s) # [2, 3]
s.remove(1) # ValueError because s does not have a 1
```

---

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code, but this is why you're getting a ValueError.

Comment: so the fix is to decrement `counter` on each iteration, because it doesn't adjust automatically. Kind of a terrible error message, though.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy It's unclear what OP is trying to do with the code.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy whoops! decrementing solved the problem but can you kindly elaborate how?

Comment: @joseville I was making a duplicate element remover in a list

Comment: @flappybird Then just use `list(set(list_of_names))`

Comment: @joseville thanks, this is OP!   I did not knew about .set() since I am a beginner

Comment: @flappybird `set([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3])` is `{1, 2, 3}`, then `list({1, 2, 3})` is `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

When all the `name` is removed from the list, the while loop does not terminate and still tries to remove the `name` which is not present in the list.

You need to decrease the value of `counter` with in the while loop, so that it terminates when there is no `name` in the list.

```
list_of_names = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
name = 0
for name in range(100):
    counter = list_of_names.count(name)
    while counter > 1:
        counter -= 1
        list_of_names.remove(name)

print(list_of_names)
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: whoops! decrementing solved the problem but can you kindly elaborate how?

Comment: @flappybird - Since you are using `while` loop, their should be a terminating condition within the loop. In this case, keep decrementing `counter` until it becomes `1`.  And all the duplicate value are removed. Put some `print` statements in- between to analysis the flow.

Comment: marvellous. thanks

Comment: If the answer was helpful accept the same. Click on ✓ option available at the left side of the answer.

Comment: yes it was, john gordons answer seemed super easy to me. If you insist,  I can accept yours as the definite anwer. I am sorry that I can't even upvote cuz I have 11 reputation.

Comment: No that's not the point. Accept the most helpful answer. No issues If you could not upvote too.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `name` inside the `list_of_names` when the `remove` is being called. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve with that code. But you can avoid that exception by adding a little check.

```
list_of_names = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
name = 0
for name in range(100):
    counter = list_of_names.count(name)
    while counter > 1 and name in list_of_names: #Add a check here to avoid the exception
            list_of_names.remove(name)

print(list_of_names)
```

Comment: if you're checking `name in list_of_names` in the while loop condition, then there's no need for `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

I found some problems:

First if all, the main reason you are getting issues is because your `counter` statement doesn't actually decrease because it is outside of the `while` statement.

I got it to work with this code:

```py
list_of_names = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
name = 0
for name in list_of_names:
  while True:
    counter = list_of_names.count(name)
    if counter < 1:
      break
    print(f"Counter: {counter}")
    print(name in list_of_names)
    print(name)
    print(list_of_names)
    list_of_names.remove(name)
            

print(list_of_names)
```